# Service Worker working locally but not registering after hosting my website

Tags: javascript, web, hosting, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Service worker is working locally in my website when i deployed it on firebase for testing purpose it was working fine there too but when i hosted my website from cPanel on my domain, service worker is not registering. Please help me to solve this problem. Attaching code and screenshots here.

index.html file

```
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register('./sw.js')
      .then(() => console.log('Service worker Registered'))
      .catch(error => console.log('some error occurred', error));
  }
</script>
```

sw.js file

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) { 
          event.waitUntil(preLoad());
      });

var preLoad = function() {
   console.log('Install Event processing');
   return caches.open('app-cache-1').then(function(cache) {
     console.log('Cached index and offline page during Install');
      return cache.addAll([
        './css/main.css',
       './css/materialize.min.css',
       './img/icons/icon-72x72.png',
       './img/icons/icon-96x96.png',
       './img/icons/icon-128x128.png',
       './img/icons/icon-144x144.png',
       './img/icons/icon-152x152.png',
       './img/icons/icon-192x192.png',
       './img/icons/icon-384x384.png',
       './img/icons/icon-512x512.png',
       './img/background-image.jpeg',
       './img/favicon.jpeg',
       './img/pp1 (2).jpeg',
       './img/pv1.jpeg',
       './img/pv10.jpg',
       './img/pv11.jpg',
       './img/pv12.jpg',
       './img/pv13.jpeg',
       './img/pv-1.jpeg',
       './img/pv-2.jpeg',
       './img/pv-3.jpeg',
       './img/pv-4.jpeg',
       './img/pv-5.jpeg',
       './js/app.js',
       './js/materialize.min.js',
       './'
     ]);
   });
};

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
 console.log('The service worker is providing the asset.');
   event.respondWith(
   checkResponse(event.request).catch(function() {
  return returnFromCache(event.request);
   })
  );
   event.waitUntil(addToCache(event.request));
  });

var checkResponse = function(request) {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    fetch(request).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 404) {
        fulfill(response);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    }, reject);
  });
};

var addToCache = function(request) {
  return caches.open('app-cache-1').then(function(cache) {
  return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Add page to offline' + response.url);
  return cache.put(request, response);
   });
 });
};

  var returnFromCache = function(request) {
  return caches.open('app-cache-1').then(function(cache) {
  return cache.match(request).then(function(matching) {
  if (!matching || matching.status == 404) {
    return cache.match('offline.html');
  } else {
    return matching;
  }
   });
 });
};
```

Screenshots of Service worker and cache while running the website locally

[Service Worker registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBqFD.png)

[Cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn5rn.png)

Comment: Using the Lighthouse test in Chrome there are no errors in the PWA section?

Comment: @Mathias while using lighthouse test there is a performance speed error locally but manifest and service worker are working fine and its 73% PWA when I deployed the website on firebase for testing purpose but when i deployed website on domain its not registering the service worker and becomes 23% PWA because of this. Any solution?

Comment: When you click on the PWA score it takes you the PWA section below and usually lists specific errors for you to research. Sometimes it also gives links to suggestions on what to fix. You are not using a port in the URL? I have seen some people have issues when they do that in the past.

Comment: @Mathias these are the errors 


3)
User will not be prompted to Install the Web App
Failures: Site does not register a service worker.
4)
Does not use HTTPS
17 insecure requests found
5)
Does not redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
6)
Does not register a service worker

Comment: Your site needs to be HTTPS. If you want to do a quick test to make sure your code is OK, upload to https://Glitch.me for free. Then work on getting a certificate for your real site. Make sure you type in HTTPS @ Glitch, else they use HTTP.

Comment: @Mathias locally its running on HTTP and works fine then why it is not registering service worker on the site after hosting on HTTP?

Comment: Perhaps they do that so you can test locally? HTTPS is required. Lighthouse will help you make things work correctly. Trust what it tells you.

Comment: Ok thank you so much.